# Can I access my Android's Micro SD card through Bluetooth?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, bluetooth, storage

I just got my first Android about a week ago; so I'm hoping to learn a thing or two about it.
One thing I've been curious about is if there's a way to access my phone on my computer through Bluetooth. I was hoping I could reformat the Micro SD card that's in my phone (because I don't have an adapter..)

Can I even do that..? If so, can I go even deeper into my phone to do other neat things?

I have the ZTE Score running Android 2.3

Answer (score 1):

If your only goal is to format the SD card, you can go to `Settings -> SD card and phone storage -> Unmount SD card` and then `Format SD card`. This should standard on all phones, at least it's on my Galaxy S.

You can use bluetooth to send/receive files to/from your phone after pairing it with your PC but not format.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do that. The only problem is, the card came with the phone, and it's split partitioned; so I'm not getting the full storage capacity of the card..

Comment: You can't get such low-level access to the card via bluetooth, you need to use a card reader or a device that can function as a card reader.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I just ordered a Micro SD to SD adapter on Amazon for 76 cents, lol.